# Option to boot to Windows 7 disappeared. Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I had a dual boot system with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. The dual boot used to work perfectly but after some days of happily using Ubuntu I realized that the option to  boot into windows 7 disappeared. 
I tried the boot repair but still my windows doesn't seem to  work.
Tried using the windows installation CD and did a repair installation but still it didn't work.
This is the summary of by boot repair.
Can someone please help  me  with this.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11142546/

Comment: Do you need Windows, or just some files?

Comment: Can you check if `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` has some content? If it has, that means that something is wrong with your BIOS.

Comment: did you run 'sudo update-grub'?

Comment: Hi David - I need windows.  Hi Dantela - /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober does have some content. and I did run update-grub

Answer (score 0):

As temporal solution, you can add these lines into `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda3)" {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='(hd0,msdos3)'
chainloader +1
}
```

then `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: After adding these in the /etc/grub.d/40_custom: I see  the option for windows 7 but it gives an error while booting into windows.  Thanks a lot for  you help  Danatela